# Brightness Keys Not Working Lenovo Edge

Tags: 16.04, brightness, xdotool

The brightness hotkeys on my lenovo edge 2-in-1 are F11 and F12, but they don't work on Ubuntu for some reason. when testing on the keyboard layout screen in the text entry settings on Ubuntu 16.04, it shows nothing happenjng when I press these keys. when running `xev` command, there is no output on the terminal when I press these keys. I tried setting the brightness hotkeys using keyboard shortcuts, which show up fine in `xev`, using `xdotool` command to simulate the brightness keys being pressed, but this doesn't work no matter what shortcut I use and in the keyboard layout, it only shows the modifier keys being pressed, never the last key in the shortcut. I should note that using the `xdotool` commands I am using work fine from the command line (using `XF86MonBrightnessUp` and `XF86MonBrightnessDown`. I found an indicator applet that I can use to control brightness to some degree, but I'd prefer to have my brightness keys working again if it is at all possible

Comment: In terminal type 'acpi_listen'. You'll have to install 'acpid' if instructed. Then use your function control keys and update your question with the terminal output.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix there is no output from 'acpi_listen' when I press the brightness keys or when I try a keyboard shortcut

Comment: Hopefully another lenovo user will respond with the proper acpi setup. I'm on my research challenged phone right now.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem with an Ideapad 500S-ISK.  All the Fn-Buttons, except the Brightness, are working. When I use Volumen Down in `acpi_listen` i get `button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K`. But when I test the screen brightness, there is no output at all.  There is a similar question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/830948/lenovo-ideapad-brightness-keys-not-generating-any-events-in-ubuntu-16-04-1

Comment: +1 Had the same issue for the Ideapad 500s. Oh, I was the asker for the question linked above. Did anyone manage to fix the issue?