# Lenovo ideapad brightness keys not generating any events in Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, lenovo, brightness, backlight

I have a new Lenovo Ideapad 500S with a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.1 running on it. Unfortunately, the brightness up/down keys don't work. (They work fine in Windows.)

Running `acpi_listen` shows me generated events for volume up/down keys, but not for brightness up/down. Running `xev` also did not give me any output for the brightness up/down keys.

After editing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line in `/etc/default/grub` several times with options like `acpi_backlight=vendor`,`video.use_native_backlight=1`, `acpi_osi=Linux` and `acpi_osi=`, I can confirm that this changes the soft links in `/sys/class/backlight/` and I currently only have `intel_backlight` there.

Running `echo <NUM> | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` works fine and changes the brightness, and so does changing it from `Settings > Brightness and Lock`.

Nothing inside Ubuntu seems to be able to detect these keys, so I'm not sure making any changes in the grub config will matter at all.

Please let me know if someone knows how to fix this and also if any additional information will be useful in debugging this issue.

**Update:**

Adding `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=intel_backlight` to the line in grub seems to make the brightness *down* key generate something in `xev` (though nothing in `acpi_listen` yet). The output is:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0xd3, subw 0x0, time 391361, (728,884), root:(793,936),
    state 0x0, keycode 120 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0xd3, subw 0x0, time 391368, (728,884), root:(793,936),
    state 0x0, keycode 120 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

**Additional outputs:**

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Skylake Integrated Graphics [17aa:3828]
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
```

Comment: Can you adjust the brightness with slider control in `System Settings`, `Brightness & Lock`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Yes, that works fine. Changing GUI settings changes the brightness.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix done.

Comment: You have the infamous `SkyLake` which might complicate things here. Also you are using `i915_bpo` kernel driver which has had some problems with people upgrading. I might have to update my answer based on these new facts....

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: I wouldn't mind downgrading straight to 14.04 (or maybe 15.X) if there isn't any direct solution for 16.04. However, if an update to your answer might give more possible options for fixing it, I look forward to what you propose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this using a couple of workarounds.

The first step was making the keys detectable. I had a laptop of a similar model (Lenovo Z400) and I looked at what keycodes were generated for it. Based on that, I put this in my `/etc/rc.local/`:

```
setkeycodes e054 225 # Brightness up -> brightness up
setkeycodes e04c 224 # Brightness down -> brightness down
```

The second step was making the keys change the brightness. I first noticed that running `xdotool key 232` and `xdotool key 233` increased and decreased the brightness perfectly (including the change notification in Unity). Then I tried two things to get the brightness to work.

First, I noticed that `xev` now showed me the events `XF86MonBrightnessUp` and `XF86MonBrightnessDown` for the two keys, which means everything was working fine at the X level. So I simply used Ubuntu's shortcut manager and registered the two keys (which were read as their XF86 equivalents) to the `xdotool` commands. This worked great!

However, some weeks later, due to some packages/drivers I changed, `xev` stopped reporting the XF86 events and so the above method did not work. However, `acpi_listen` showed that `video/brightnessdown` and `video/brightnessup` events were being generated, so then, after some googling, I put the following in a new file, `/etc/acpi/events/ideapad-monitor-brightness-up`:

```bash
# same event as reported by acpi_listen
event=video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000 K
action=su vivek -c "export DISPLAY=:0.0; xdotool getactivewindow && xdotool key 233 2>&1 > /tmp/log"
# The redirection into /tmp/log probably doesn't make any difference
```

and also an equivalent `ideapad-monitor-brightness-down` file with `xdotool key 232` and that solved the problem. Haven't had any problems since. :)

Comment: I have this problem but acpi_listen won't react to these buttons as well

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had problems with brightness keys since 2012 with my older laptop (Toshiba Satellite Core 2 Duo) under Ubuntu 14.04 but it appears many users have. The most popular solution is to **create the file** by typing:

```
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

then **edit the file** using:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

then **populate the file** with:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

**Save** and **reboot**.

**Note** the `BusID` should match the output of:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga
```

Also replace **intel_backlight** above with what appears in `lspci` command if different.

Another option to try is change grub command line with `acpi_backlight=vendor`.

### Update

I just stumbled across this Ubuntu webpage on brightness keys: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight

When I upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 it brought with it Kernel 16.04 and I had all types of problems with suspend/resume, thin fonts, black screens instead of wallpaper,  higher than normal CPU usage and hotter than normal temperatures. I wrote up many of the steps I took in this answer: [Ubuntu 15.10: Various "types" of freezes and now unexpected shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827939/ubuntu-15-10-various-types-of-freezes-and-now-unexpected-shutdown/828027#828027) which solved most my problems on an Intel Ivy Bridge platform and it may very well help your Sky Lake platform.

Comment: I had tried both of these earlier, but I tried them again. Didn't notice any change in the behaviour. Brightness still doesn't change, `acpi_listen` still doesn't notice anything and `xev` gives me the same output as in the question update. :/

Comment: Try using the grub kernel parameter `acpi_osi= ` (blank) and remove `acpi_backlight=vendor` if it's still there.

Comment: Tried this once before and again now. Didn't fix the issue.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is grub kernel parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`. It will make your laptop run a little hotter and battery will drain faster so if it doesn't work remove it. I did find one user who claims this works `quite splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=’!Windows 2012′ acpi=force acpi_enforce_resources=lax drm.vblankoffdelay=1 acpi_backlight=vendor video.use_native_backlight=1`

Comment: @VivekGhaisas I updated the answer with all I can think of tonight. Sorry you didn't have success to date :(

Comment: I've posted a follow-up as an answer for how I finally solved the problem. Thanks a lot for your help!