# setkeycodes does not change keycode

Tags: 16.04, xorg, shortcut-keys, backlight, keycodes

I have a fresh install of 16.04 on a new Levono Ideapad 500S. I've been [trying to make the brightness keys work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/830948/lenovo-ideapad-brightness-keys-not-generating-any-events-in-ubuntu-16-04-1) and have finally managed to hook up the brightness up key to work as expected.

However, I need to change the keycode of my brightness down key in order for it to work, but `setkeycodes` does not seem to be doing anything.

Running `showkey` and pressing the brightness down button thrice gives me:

```
$ sudo showkey -s
kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
0x9c 
0xe0 0x6f 0xe0 0xef 
0xe0 0x6f 0xe0 0xef 
0xe0 0x6f 0xe0 0xef
```

which led me to believe that the scancode of it is `e06f`. However, running `sudo setkeycodes e06f 224` and then running `showkey -k` still shows the old key code (which was 112).

Can setkeycodes not override an already set keycode from some other source? If so, how can I change the brightness down key's keycode.

Answer (score 1):

`setkeycodes` will change the key mappings at kernel level itself.
Here there is an issue in understanding the scan code values.
For key press it's: `0x6f` and for release it's :`0xef`.
So the command you need to run is :

```
sudo setkeycodes 6fef 224
```

This will change the mapping to the desired one.

Comment: I've tried doing exactly this with `TAB` (`0x3a 0xba`) to use it as `ESC` (`1`) by running `setkeycodes 3aba 1`. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a little bit to figure out the gotcha with trying to do mappings on a PS/2 keyboard with `showkey` and `setkeycodes`.

As hinted at on [the man page for setkeycodes](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setkeycodes), there is a problem that affects tools that report scan codes such as `showkey -s` in the sense that they don't show the actual scan codes that are appropriate input for `setkeycodes`:

> In 2.6 kernels raw mode, or scancode mode, is not very raw at all.

After relying on the output of `showkey -s` for a bit and noticing my mappings of existing keys not working and some other keys I hadn't thought I was modifying getting changed, eventually I realized that scan codes from `showkey -s` were the common factor in the problem cases.

Instead, if you must use `showkey`, use regular `showkey` output (without `-s`) to find the current mapped keycode for the key, and work backwards through the table from `getkeycodes` to figure out the key's scan code. If there are multiple scan codes mapped to the same keycode, it may take a little mastermind and/or trial and error to work out the right scan code for the key.

Or, rely on other sources of scan code information such as `atkbd` log messages in `dmesg` output (use `dmesg -w` to follow `dmesg` output), or the scan codes reported by `evtest` if your system is using the event device framework.